# A strange problem with rendering glass in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, mesh, topology, glass

While I look on my model by <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> *(in viewport)* it looks good:
[image: Good looking model.]
*Render without wired connections to the center*

But when I render same scene out it looks like this:
[image: Something wrong.]

*I think this is caused by wrong topology, but still - in preview-mode it looks good, can I do something to make render like 'preview render'?*

There is photo of the topology:
[image: topo]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After pressing random buttons, and trying to fix mesh - successfully i did it!
There was problem with my mesh - gaps caused mirror modifier, and some other things.

### There is how I fixed it:

At first I was searching for something wired in mesh, found not connected edges, so I selected them.[image: selecting edges]

And scaled them down. *pressed **s** + **x** (axis of scaling) + entered **0** on keyboard*
[image: connecting edges]

After scaling them together i removed doubles by selecting all edges *press two times **a*** then click ***w > Remove Doubles***
[image: parsing together]
[image]

In the end, with selected mesh I pressed **Mesh>Clean up>Split Concave Faces**...
[image: clean up]

## And Voilà!

[image: fin]
 :)

Answer (score 3):

It does look a topology issue.  And the most likely cause is a subdivision surface modifier that has different values for render and preview.  Set them to the same value and see if your new render matches your new preview.

The topology issue is either than those faces are not sufficiently planar or aren't adequately controlled with control loops.  The way that you structured the central circles, you virtually have a megapole, and the fact that it's not really, not quite a pole doesn't matter.  But megapoles are fine, provided their component faces are coplanar, including coplanar control loops.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Unfortunately, I have not used subsurface modifier in this project, although I will keep your protip in mind. :)